# Turn ForeignKey Objects to ChoicesField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model called `Space` and it has a field called `guest`, and the field is a choicefield that takes a single number, lets say `3` and save it in database. I have another model called `Book` and among its fields is `no_of_persons`.

Now, is it possible for me to filter the `'guest'` field value which is `'3'` through `Book` model and display it as dropdown (1,2,3) that won't exceed the number saved in `guest` model.?

Recall, `guest` is saved as a single digit. Is it possible to make it display like dropdown starting from the lowest number?

A good example of what I'm trying to do is how the value of 'Guests' field on Airbnb corresponds with 'Guests' field in its 'Booking' model.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Getting the below error after trying the suggestion by Todor.

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Models

```
class Space(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User)
    no_of_guest=models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=MAX_SPACE_CHOICES, verbose_name='no_of_guest')
    #other fields

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.user, self.id, self.name, self.address, self.no_of_guest)

class BookSpace(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User)
    space= models.ForeignKey(Space)
    check_in_date= models.DateField()
    check_out_date= models.DateField()
    no_of_persons= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #other fields

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s' % (self.user, self.space, self.full_name)

class BookSpaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= BookSpace
        exclude=('#fields not needed')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        space= kwargs.pop('space')
        super(BookSpaceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        guest_choices= [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1,  int(space.no_of_guest)+1)]
        self.fields['no_of_persons'].widget=  forms.ChoiceField(choices=guest_choices)
```

After updating, I'm getting

KeyError 
u'space'
Exception Location: models.py in **init**, line 202

The line is:

```
space= kwargs.pop('space')
```

In my views:

```
def book_a_space(request, space_id):
    space= Space.objects.get(pk=space_id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=BookSpaceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #other data and more
        else:
            print form.errors

    else:
        form=BookSpaceForm(space=space)
        return render(request, 'spaceb/book_space_form.html', {'BookSpaceForm':BookSpaceForm})
```

In Template:

```
{{  BookSpaceForm.as_p }}
```

UPDATE:

Still getting the KeyError. I modified the models like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    space_id= kwargs.pop('space_id')
    super(BookSpaceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if space_id:
        guest_choices = [(str(i), str(i)) for i in range(1, int(space_id.no_of_guest)+1)]
        self.fields['no_of_persons'].widget = forms.ChoiceField(choices=guest_choices)
```

And in my views, I did

```
def book_a_space(request, space_id):
        space= Space.objects.get(pk=space_id)
        if request.method=="POST":
            form=BookSpaceForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #other data and more
            else:
               print form.errors

        else:
            context = {
               'BookSpaceForm': BookSpaceForm(space_id=space_id),
                'space_id': Space.objects.get(id=space_id)
            }
           return render(request, 'spaceb/book_space_form.html', context)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
 'unicode' object has no attribute 'no_of_guest'
```

I changed the **unicode** in BookSpace models to return:

```
return '%s, %s, %s' % (self.user, self.space_id.no_of_guest, self.full_name)
```

Yet.. still getting the same unicode error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `Book` form which accepts a `guest` instance at construction time and dynamically change the widget for the `no_of_persons` field with a select box.

An example implementation:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        space = kwargs.pop('space')
        super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        guest_choices = [(str(i), str(i)) for i in range(1, int(space.no_of_guest)+1)]
        self.fields['no_of_persons'].widget = forms.Select(choices=guest_choices)


#sample usage
def book_a_space(request, space_id):
    space = Space.objects.get(pk=space_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookSpaceForm(request.POST, space=space)
        if form.is_valid():
            #other data and more
        else:
           print form.errors
    else:
        form = BookSpaceForm(space=space)

    return render(request, 'spaceb/book_space_form.html', {
        'form': form,
        'space': space,
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The main problem here is changing the 3 into dropdown like (1,2,3). I'm finding it to figure out how to go about it.

Comment: @YoYo I've update my answer with a sample example, hope it helps.

Comment: I'm getting this error: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found on this line guest_choices = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, space.guest+1)] I tried guest_choices= [(i, int(str(i))) for i in range(1, sharedcrib.no_of_guest+1)] yet still the same error

Comment: You can't get this error from this line, its something else. Would be easier to debug if you provide you models definition in the question. However you can try to use `ChoiceField` instead of `TypedChoiceField`.

Comment: Well, it seems like you use CharField for `no_of_guest` and `no_of_persons` which IMO is not very correct since that are numbers. However I updated my answer with `ChoiceField` now should be OK.

Comment: What fields do you think will be appropriate? Also I tried your new update and KeyError pop up. I've updated the question.

Comment: `IntegerField` should be more appropriate ? About the error: when you have POST request you construct the form: `form=BookSpaceForm(request.POST)` without sending space, e.g. you need to `form=BookSpaceForm(request.POST, space=space)`

Comment: I will try other fields  later.. just want to fix this and see how it works first. I've added your new answer but still getting the same KeyError. I've modified the code and I'm now getting unicode error. Kindly check the updated question. :(

Comment: When `request.method=="POST":` you are (again) creating the `form` without sending `space`. And the code inside `BookForm.__init__` is expecting `space` object to be send (not `space_id`) that's why you get `'unicode' object has no attribute 'no_of_guest'`, because `space_id` is an `unicode` object not `space` object. These are very simple mistakes, if you don't understand the code and why you are getting these error my advice is to better stop, try to explain in to yourself and get back when everything clears up in your mind. This is not relevant to Django but a lack of Python & OOP skills.